# Same asynctask but different result handling in onPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Currently I have an AsyncTask declared both in my main activity class and in my widget class. The code is the same except for the result handling in `onPostExecute` (in activity the result retrieved goes to a textview within activity and in the widget it goes to a textview in my widget).

I'd like to move the `AsyncTask` to an external java file (to avoid code duplication) and somehow call it from other different classes (like my widget and main activity) with different result handling. I guess I can't just pass a method name as a parameter to call it from `onPostExecute`, but is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **NO**, you cannot do anything about this. In general, `AsyncTask`s are `Activity`-specific, and are defined as inner classes inside different `Activity`s so that they have access to methods defined in that `Activity`.

You can go ahead and define the same `AsyncTask` inside the `Activity` and the widget.

Comment: I will , I just wait a bit to see if somebody has different information :) Could happen, right? ;-)